# This Kotlin Singleton implementation, will become elegible for Garbage Collection?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, garbage-collection

I have this class acting like a singleton (the instance is not being secured to be recreated again):

```
class FooInteractorFactory(private val someEvent: SomeEvent) {

    companion object {

        lateinit var fooFactory: FooInteractorFactory

        fun initialize(someEvent: SomeEvent) {
            fooFactory = FooInteractorFactory(someEvent)
        }
    }

    fun createSomeObject(): SomeObject {
        return SomeObject(someEvent)
    }

}
```

That "singleton" is being initialized inside this class:

```
class FooImpl : SomeEvent {

    init {
        FooInteractorFactory.initialize(this)
    }

    ...
}
```

And `FooImpl` is being instantiated inside a lifecycle function `onCreate()` in an Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       val foompl = FooImpl()
    }

    ...

}
```

My question here is `FooInteractorFactory`, `SomeEvent` or `SomeObject` some of them will be leaked or not eligible for Garbage Collection?

As the documentation says,

> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

this is gonna be eligible, BUT, I'm not sure. I just add to the app LeakCanary, but, the Leak never happened.

I want to be sure based on the experience of each of you.

**EDIT**

This is how the `FooInteractorFactory` looks in decompiled java code:

```
public final class FooInteractorFactory {
   private final SomeEvent someEvent;
   @NotNull
   public static FooInteractorFactory fooFactory;

   @NotNull
   public final FooInteractorFactory createSomeObject() {
      return new SomeObject(this.someEvent);
   }

   public FooInteractorFactory(@NotNull SomeEvent someEvent) {
      this.someEvent = someEvent;
   }


   public static final class Companion {
      @NotNull
      public final FooInteractorFactory getFooFactory() {
         return FooInteractorFactory.access$getFooFactory$cp();
      }

      public final void setFooFactory(@NotNull FooInteractorFactory var1) {
         FooInteractorFactory.fooFactory = var1;
      }

      public final void initialize(@NotNull SomeEvent someEvent) {
         ((FooInteractorFactory.Companion)this).setFooFactory(new FooInteractorFactory(someEvent));
      }
  }

}
```

`FooInteractorFactory` is a static reference of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK LeakCanary detects only leaked activities, so it is not designed to detect all memory leaks (finally, how should it now which instance should be garbage collected and which is not?).

Also, what you've attached as a quote is about `Class<?>`, not about instance. I mean, it says about whole `Class` definitions, that are being stored in Permanent Generation or Metaspace (depends on Java version).

And about your question: garbage collector usually works in the next way - it starts from references named GC roots, then goes through all the objects via references from these roots, marks them as "alive", and reclaims memory from all the objects that were not marked as alive (I mean, that are not available through GC-roots). References known as GC-roots are :

1. Local variables
2. `static` variables
3. Active `Thread`s
4. JNI references

I doubt any of `Class` objects that you have mentioned are going to be unloaded from JVM in case you haven't define your own `ClassLoader` or messed with their lifecycle.
Talking about instances:

> I have this class acting like a singleton (the instance is not being secured to be recreated again)

If comanion's object `fooFactory` reference referred object `A` and then was reassigned with object `B`, then if `A` is not referenced with any other GC-roots or intermediate references that are available through GC-roots, than in few GC cycles this intance will be garbage collected.

The same goes for all the other instances.

Comment: @AndreyLlyunin thank you for answering! well, so, having the class decompiled, the static reference to `FooInteractorFactory` make it not eligible for garbage collection, BUT, having in mind that `FooInteractorFactory` is being used (not referenced, not assigned) inside another class which is `FooImpl` this class is gonna be removed, so their members and usages as well? (FooInteractorFactory)

Comment: Talking about **instances** - they will be collected if aren't referenced directly or transitively by local references of static references of `Class` objects that are contained in PermGen or Metaspace already (let's forget about JNI and threads here). So, assuming that `val foompl = FooImpl()` will be used only in the context of `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`, then it will be collected in a few GC cycles after this method execution will be finished.

Comment: BUT (!) because `FooImpl` requested a class `FooInteractorFactory` and invoked a static method which initializes the factory with a reference to itself (to `FooImpl`), than static reference which will point to a `FooInteractorFactory` object (that won't be GC-collected until this object will be **unreferenced**, for instance, by future invocation of `initialize` method), than this `FooImpl` instance will be available from two GC-roots: static reference on `FooInteractorFactory` which contains `FooImpl` object as a member, and local variable `val foompl = ...` in `onCreate`.

Comment: As a summary: `FooImpl` instance won't be lost until two events will happen:
1. `onCreate` method execution will be finished and local reference `foompl` that points to the instance will be lost (assuming that it won't be passed to an object with bigger lifetime inside this method)
2. Reference `fooFactory` that points to `FooInteractorFactory` (that stores the instance of `FooImpl` that was passed from the `init` block of `FooImpl`) will change it's value due to another `initialize` method invocation of `FooInteractorFactory`'s `companion object`.